# How to insert 3 blank lines in python after each grade

Tags: python, csv

I'm combining to different csv files into a single new csv file. The first csv file is of absentees and in the new csv file I want 3 blank lines to be entered AFTER the absentee data.
In the second csv file is the list of present people from each grade. I want to  insert 3 blank lines AFTER each grade.

The code I have so far is:

```
import csv
with open('Inschool.csv') as f:
    reader =  csv.reader(f)
    in_school = list(reader)
with open('notinschool.csv') as f:
    reader =  csv.reader(f)
    not_in_school = list(reader)
for grade, name, status, hr_teacher in not_in_school:
    print grade, name, status, hr_teacher
for grade, name, status, hr_teacher in in_school:
    print grade, name, status, hr_teacher
iFile = open('Inschool.csv',)
reader = csv.reader(iFile)
IFILE = open('notinschool.csv')
READER = csv.reader(IFILE)
oFile = open('combined.csv','wb')
writer = csv.writer(oFile, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in READER:
    writer.writerow(row)
    writer.writerow([])
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Do you know if the data is sorted by grade?

Comment: Please describe what the problem(s) are with your current code. Also, is the input data in the two csv file grouped by grade or in random order?

Comment: You can put three blank lines in the output csv by removing the `writer.writerow([])` in the initial `for row in READER:` loop and adding the statement `writer.writerows([[] for _ in xrange(3)])` between it and the following `for row in reader:` loop.

Comment: @martineau That helped in getting the 3 lines at the end. Thanks. Is it possible to get 3 blank lines between each grade in the - row in reader: ; -part? Eg: 7 grade 2 people one after another then 3 blank lines and the grade 3 people and so on

Comment: You could keep track of the last grade seen and conditionally writerows every time the current one is different from that. Just initialize `last_grade_seen = None` before entering the `for` loop then use `last_grade_seen = row[0]` inside the loop. To test whether to write the blank lines use `if row[0] != last_grade_seen:` (before updating it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? Try adding the lineterminator argument to csv.writer as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

with open('Inschool.csv') as f:
    reader =  csv.reader(f)
    in_school = list(reader)

with open('notinschool.csv') as f:
    reader =  csv.reader(f)
    not_in_school = list(reader)

for grade, name, status, hr_teacher in not_in_school:
    print grade, name, status, hr_teacher
for grade, name, status, hr_teacher in in_school:
    print grade, name, status, hr_teacher

iFile = open('Inschool.csv',)
reader = csv.reader(iFile)
IFILE = open('notinschool.csv')
READER = csv.reader(IFILE)
oFile = open('combined.csv','wb')
writer_a = csv.writer(oFile, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer_b = csv.writer(oFile, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator="\n\n\n\n")

for row in READER:
     writer_a.writerow(row)

writer_b.writerow([])

for row in reader:
     writer_b.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, though this allows me to get 3 lines after the absentee file, It is unable to separate the different grades in the present file with 3 blank rows. Would appreciate if you could help with that too but really,
Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open(basedir+'inschool.csv') as file_to_open:
    file_to_read =  csv.reader(file_to_open)
    in_school = list(file_to_read)

with open(basedir+'notinschool.csv') as file_to_open:
    file_to_read =  csv.reader(file_to_open)
    not_in_school = list(file_to_read)

for grade, name, status, hr_teacher in in_school:
    print grade, name, status, hr_teacher

for grade, name, status, hr_teacher in not_in_school:
    print grade, name, status, hr_teacher

attended_file = open(basedir+'inschool.csv', 'r')
attended_reg = csv.reader(attended_file)

not_attended_file = open(basedir+'notinschool.csv', 'r')
not_in_reg = csv.reader(not_attended_file)


combine_file = open(basedir+'combined.csv','a+')
writer = csv.writer(combine_file, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for row in not_in_reg:
    writer.writerow(row)

writer.writerow('')
writer.writerow('')
writer.writerow('')

for row in attended_reg:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I've changed out the names a bit to make it easier to follow as well. If you could add a sample of your CSV  I can provide a better option too